# Bulk call generation using asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk, billing, pbx, agi

I m trying to generate bulk calls using asterisk, everything is working fine . I am using call files to do this,  but the problem is in billing (That i want to save to other database using AGI) . How can i know that the call is answered , unanswered ,Busy, not responding etc. I know about `${DIALSTATUS}` but its not working if you generate calls from .call file.

my call file looks like this :

`Channel: Dahdi/ch/somenumber 

Context: mycontext

Extension: exten

MaxRetries: 3

RetryTime: 40

WaitTime: 25`

Let me know what other information you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have read asterisk book.

I recomend ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony".

You can do outbound call via dialplan by using

```
Channel: Local/somenumber@somecontext/n
```

Anyway it is very  bad idea create dialler(very complex task actually) yourself with your level of questions. Check vicidial software or other opensource already written diallers

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i have already tried Channel:local/ext@context  , thats why i asked here , anyway i got working, now i can call from call files and store UNANSWERED and ANSWER calls separately into the database . Done this after few hrs of asking the question, forgot to mention here :)